# remote: Repository not found -while git push

Tags: github, next.js, next.js13

when I try to a next JS project  to this repository -'https://github.com/SRIDEV1999/stack_overflow_nextjs14.git/' .
It says remote: Repository not found. fatal: repository 'https://github.com/SRIDEV1999/stack_overflow_nextjs14.git/' not found
How can I push my project to this repository

when I try git push - (remote: Repository not found. fatal: repository 'https://github.com/SRIDEV1999/stack_overflow_nextjs14.git/' not found) this error is showed in vs terminal'

Answer (score 0):

Try this command:

```
git remote set-url origin https://SRIDEV1999@github.com/SRIDEV1999/stack_overflow_nextjs14.git/
```

This command updates the remote URL for the "origin" remote in your Git configuration. After running this command, subsequent Git operations that involve the remote will use the updated URL with the specified username.

**Note:** If you're facing issues related to authentication, consider using SSH or HTTPS with a personal access token for enhanced security.